# Sharepoint Updating MMS DocumentSet field

Tags: asp.net

I have am writing some SharePoint 2013 integration to my companies product, to upload a document set with metadata and then upload some documents. I have all this functionality working correctly, except for updating Document Set metadata fields that require MMS (Managed Metadata Service) fields.

```
dim docSetUrl as string = "http://someurl/"
Dim folder = Context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(docSetUrl)
Context.Load(folder)
Context.ExecuteQuery()
folder.Properties.Item("GeoObject") = "test" 'Normal string content (updates correctly)
folder.Properties.Item("Applicant") = "1353;#: Value A : REC-95342|9074b95b-9dcd-4c93-b548-32a5c7e7e083" 'Does not update correctly
folder.Update()
Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Now as you can see from the code, I can update the **GeoObject** which just requires a string value, but for the Applicant object which is a MMS type, it just doesn't change (no errors).

If I log into SharePoint and manually use MMS to select an item, and then programatically check what it's value is : **353;#: Value A : REC-95342|9074b95b-9dcd-4c93-b548-32a5c7e7e083**, if I clear the value manually and then try to push the found value back in, I still have no result.

How am I supposed to update a MMS field?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating a MM field is a little different to a single line of text field! You have to create an object of type `TaxonomyFieldValue` then set the GUID and label to the field and then you can set the field to this object.

(I am a C# programmer, so apology to not be able to give you the code in VB, but you get the idea!)

```
                        TaxonomyField taxonomyField = list.Fields["TaxonomyField"]as TaxonomyField;
                        TaxonomyFieldValue taxonomyFieldValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(taxonomyField);
                        taxonomyFieldValue.TermGuid = term.Id.ToString();
                        taxonomyFieldValue.Label = term.Name;
                        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                        item["Title"] ="Sample";
                        item["TaxonomyField"] = taxonomyFieldValue;
                        item.Update();
                        list.Update();
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, that is fine I prefer C#, but current product was originally written in vb.net so I just copied straight from. Problem with your code is I am using the 2013 client tools, so objects like SPListItem do not exist, are you able to assist for the 2013 client tools implementation?

Comment: here is another link to update a Taxonomy field in 2013:

https://unnieayilliath.com/2015/08/24/sharepoint-2013-updateclear-taxonomy-field-value-using-c-csom/

another link:

http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.com/2013/12/a-quick-guide-to-getting-and-setting.html


I can update this post later when I find the code I wrote to update a Taxonomy field in one of my last projects

Comment: Thanks for both of those links, the first link suited the assemblies I am using. The only thing I am trying to understand now is how to identify the List value that comes as a parameter in the function. Using the code I have, how can I identify the List inside the folder? The folder does not seem to have any properties to return a List, other than ListItemAllFields which returns a ListItem which again appears incompatible. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I fiddled around and was able to finish the last bit myself. 
I posted a full solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064033/sharepoint-updating-mms-documentset-field/